# Ensures Unproven via property when implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I'm trying what, to me, seems like some fairly basic code contracts code. I've reduced it down to the following problem. The following fails the static analysis, with the message

> CodeContracts: ensures unproven:
>   this.Frozen

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace PlayAreaCollection2010
{
    public class StrippedContract : IBasic
    {
        private bool _frozen = false;

        public void Freeze()
        {
            _frozen = true;
        }

        public bool Frozen { get { return _frozen; } }
    }

    [ContractClass(typeof(IBasicContract))]
    public interface IBasic
    {
        void Freeze();
        bool Frozen { get; }
    }

    [ContractClassFor(typeof(IBasic))]
    public abstract class IBasicContract : IBasic 
    {
        #region IBasic Members

        public void Freeze()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(this.Frozen);
        }

        public bool Frozen
        {
            get { return true;}
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

However, the following works fine and satisfies all checks:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace PlayAreaCollection2010
{
    public class StrippedContract
    {
        private bool _frozen = false;

        public void Freeze()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(this.Frozen);
            _frozen = true;
        }

        public bool Frozen { get { return _frozen; } }
    }

}
```

> CodeContracts: Checked 1 assertion: 1 correct

What do I need to do to satisfy the static checker, when I've placed my contracts in the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your implementation of `IBasic`, `StrippedContract`, you will need to add a post-condition to the `Frozen` property:

```
public bool Frozen {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<bool>() == this._frozen);
        return _frozen;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the `-infer` command line option to the static checker in the Code Contracts tab of your project's properties. That will allow the static checker to infer this automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Just taken a quick google, but no help - why is the checker able to make this inference when the contract is on the class itself, but not when defined on an interface?