# Unproven Ensure that references another property in combination with an interface

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

Assume the following code:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(ICC4Contract))]
public interface ICC4
{
    bool IsFooSet { get; }
    string Foo { get; }
}

public class CC4 : ICC4
{
    private string _foo;

    public bool IsFooSet { get { return Foo != null; } }

    public string Foo { get { return _foo; } }
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(ICC4))]
public abstract class ICC4Contract : ICC4
{
    public bool IsFooSet
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures((Contract.Result<bool>() && Foo != null)
                             || !Contract.Result<bool>());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures((Contract.Result<string>() != null && IsFooSet)
                             || !IsFooSet);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The contracts try to say:

1. `IsFooSet` will return `true` if `Foo` is not `null`.
2. `Foo` doesn't return `null` if `IsFooSet` returns `true`.

This almost works.
However, I get an "ensures unproven" on `return _foo;`, because the checker doesn't realize that `Foo` will always equal `_foo`.

Changing `Foo` to an automatic property with a `private` setter removes that warning, but I don't want to do that (I don't like automatic properties with private setters).

**What do I have to change in the above code to make the warning go away while preserving the `_foo` field?**

The following doesn't work:

1. Changing `IsFooSet` to use `_foo` instead of `Foo`. It will result in an additional "ensures unproven" on `IsFooSet`.
2. Adding an invariant `Foo == _foo`. This will result in an "invariant unproven" on the implicit, default constructor. Furthermore, on a real code-base the processing time of the static checker will be magnitudes higher.
3. Adding `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == _foo);` to the getter of `Foo` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730682/572644) doesn't change anything.

Comment: This won't help with your issue, but may I ask you why you don't like automatic properties with private setters?

Comment: Most of the time, those properties are invariants of a class, i.e. the backing field should be made readonly. That's not possible with an automatic property. I actually try to completely avoid automatic properties. Reasons are outlined [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/26/CodeSmellAutomaticProperty.aspx).

Comment: Would it be removed if you set `_foo` to an empty string by default? It feels like the problem is more that the default value of `_foo` is going to be `null`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: No, that doesn't change anything. Why should it? The default value of `_foo` has no impact on the defined contracts.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I was working off the assumption that the only reality the compiler would have is the default value of `_foo` which breaks the contract.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: That assumption isn't correct. Furthermore, `_foo` being `null` doesn't actually break the contract.

Comment: I totally agree with Daniel wrt private properties. `readonly` properties ensure that you don't change them outside the constructor; when you're reading the code, you can be sure that the fields won't be changing (even though the fields themselves might be mutable).

Answer (score 2):

You can use short-circuiting to simplify the condition, and that works for some reason:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(ICC4))]
public abstract class ICC4Contract : ICC4
{
    public bool IsFooSet
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<bool>() || Foo != null);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!IsFooSet || Contract.Result<string>() != null);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```